# raise ValueError( --> 182 "Could not find a format to read the specified file in %s mode" % modename

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

Both of these code throw an error. I am not sure what is the exact cause? I am running using Jupyter notebook.

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import os
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
from torch.autograd import Variable
import pandas as pd
from skimage import io, transform
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms, utils

def show_landmarks(image, landmarks):
    """Show image with landmarks"""
    plt.imshow(image)
    plt.scatter(landmarks[:, 0], landmarks[:, 1], s=80, marker='.', c='b')
    plt.pause(0.001)  # pause a bit so that plots are updated

plt.figure()
img_name = "faces/person-7.jpg"
print(img_name)

img = io.imread(img_name)
print('here')
show_landmarks(img, landmarks)
plt.show()

###def show_landmarks(image, landmarks):
###    """Show image with landmarks"""
###    plt.imshow(image)
###    plt.scatter(landmarks[:, 0], landmarks[:, 1], s=10, marker='.', c='r')
###    plt.pause(0.001)  # pause a bit so that plots are updated

###plt.figure()
###show_landmarks(io.imread(os.path.join('data/faces/', img_name)),
###               landmarks)
###plt.show()
```

The error is:

```
faces/person-7.jpg

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-972bef8edc6f> in <module>
      9 print(img_name)
     10 
---> 11 img = io.imread(img_name)
     12 print('here')
     13 show_landmarks(img, landmarks)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/io/_io.py in imread(fname, as_gray, plugin, **plugin_args)
     46 
     47     with file_or_url_context(fname) as fname:
---> 48         img = call_plugin('imread', fname, plugin=plugin, **plugin_args)
     49 
     50     if not hasattr(img, 'ndim'):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py in call_plugin(kind, *args, **kwargs)
    207                                (plugin, kind))
    208 
--> 209     return func(*args, **kwargs)
    210 
    211 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/skimage/io/_plugins/imageio_plugin.py in imread(*args, **kwargs)
      8 @wraps(imageio_imread)
      9 def imread(*args, **kwargs):
---> 10     return np.asarray(imageio_imread(*args, **kwargs))

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py in imread(uri, format, **kwargs)
    263 
    264     # Get reader and read first
--> 265     reader = read(uri, format, "i", **kwargs)
    266     with reader:
    267         return reader.get_data(0)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/imageio/core/functions.py in get_reader(uri, format, mode, **kwargs)
    180         modename = MODENAMES.get(mode, mode)
    181         raise ValueError(
--> 182             "Could not find a format to read the specified file in %s mode" % modename
    183         )
    184 

ValueError: Could not find a format to read the specified file in single-image mode

<Figure size 432x288 with 0 Axes>
```

Comment: can you show the imports?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/BnLKFTHC

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/BnLKFTHC

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be related to *line 11 - img = io.imread(img_name)*. This error is likely being thrown, because you aren't using the optional *pluginstr* with *imread* or because *imread* cannot find a suitable plugin to read the image file.

**skimage.io.imread with parameters:**

```
skimage.io.imread(fname, as_gray=False, plugin=None, **plugin_args)

pluginstr, optional
Name of plugin to use. By default, the different plugins are tried (starting with imageio) until a suitable candidate is found. If not given and fname is a tiff file, the tifffile plugin will be used.
```

You can troubleshoot the error, by trying various plugins like the example below shows:

```
io.imread(f.name, plugin="tifffile")
```

Here is a list of available [plugins](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html)